# Awesomplete - Take option value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I asked a question about of typeahead but nobody answered me and i change plugin and i used Awesomplete from this link:

[Awesomplete plugin](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/)

Now I ask how can I take an `option` value from this code in jQuery inside awesomplete.js code:

```
<input id="testoNome" class="awesomplete testocss" style="width:166 !important;" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list">
<datalist id="listClienti">
    <option value="1">Cristian Capannini</option>
    <option value="2">Cristopher Capannini</option>
    <option value="3">Luigi Russo</option>
    <option value="4">Luca Russo</option>
    <option value="25">dsfsdf dsfsdf</option>
    <option value="26">asdasd asdasdasd</option>
    <option value="27">11111 11111</option>
    <option value="28">Luca Cecchini</option>
    <option value="29">xxxxx xxxxx</option>
    <option value="30">Maurizio Pippetta</option>
    <option value="31">Maurizio Pippetta</option>
    <option value="32">Pinco Pallino</option>
    <option value="33">sfsf sdfsdf</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bit tricky but i got it for my ajax-generated list. Try it for your static version:

```
$yourAwesomeplete.on('awesomplete-selectcomplete', function(e) {
  value = e.originalEvent.text.value;
  label = e.originalEvent.text.label;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can get the selected value by using this code

```
$(".awesomplete input").val()
```